# asp.net c# how to get value from href?

Tags: c#, href

I have a page MojiAlbumi.aspx where is this line of code: 
 href='Album.aspx?album="+id_galerija +"'

On click, you get redirected to Album.aspx where i'd like to access  to the value written in the link "Album.aspx?album='xxx'". How could I do that if it's possible to save it in some string?

Is it only possible with getting link and spliting it with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
string album = c.Request["album"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it  using

```
Request.QueryString["album"]
```

Comment: Did you try this one ?? what problem you are facing